# Finding modifications to model database

Tags: sql-server, configuration

There are ways already to compare sp_configure values for an instance and review all non-default settings.

Assuming that the model database of an instance has been modified from its original settings, is there a way to discover all non-default configurations and properties for a user database, specifically model?

Thanks,

Comment: I think the only way really would be to compare that copy of model with one you know hasn't been touched (it would also have to be the same version) or against a list of "default" properties you manually collect.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that's what I thought, but wanted to be sure since I have to review over a dozen instances.

Comment: The database configurations are stored in sys.databases, as Aaron says get a clean (new install) copy and then do a little bit of TSQL.
The default values & whether they can be ammended  are listed in BoL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-ver15